# query that get all results (including when condition not satisfied)

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get a count with these query. I would like that it shows me all nameHost (althought the count was 0) but with these query, . Without where clause I don't have any problem but with where clause don't shows me the nameHost g.Could you help me please?

Example of tables:

```
nodes         
=======
nameHost        nodeid
---------       -------
a               a
b               b
b               f
e               e
g               g


jobsDefinition
================
node_id        job_name      app
----------     -----------   ---
a               fruit        one
b               apple        two
c               iron         three
a               banana       four
f               orange       four
g               gold         five
```

The output would be:

```
a 2 (fruit,banana)
b 2 (apple,orange)
e 0
***g 0 --> **this record not show me*****
```

These is my code

```
  SELECT n.namehost,
         COUNT (jd.node_id) AS Cnt,
         LISTAGG (jd.job_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) JB_NM
    FROM nodes n 
    LEFT JOIN jobdef jd 
    ON n.nodeid = jd.node_id
--sentence where
WHERE APP NOT LIKE 'five' 
GROUP BY n.namehost
ORDER BY namehost;
```

Thanks and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the condition in the `ON` clause instead of `where`.

```
  SELECT n.namehost,
         COUNT (jd.node_id) AS Cnt,
         LISTAGG (jd.job_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) JB_NM
    FROM nodes n 
    LEFT JOIN jobdef jd 
    ON n.nodeid = jd.node_id
AND APP NOT LIKE 'five' 
GROUP BY n.namehost
ORDER BY namehost;
```

Comment: Many thanks!!! it works! So what the difference between where outside on and inside on?

Comment: @defekas17 Think of an outer join operation as being done in three stages. First an inner join with the same ON conditions; then add more rows to make an "outer" join; then apply the conditions from the WHERE clause. If the conditions involve columns from the "second" table, those columns will be null for the "outer" join rows, so in most cases those rows would be rejected by the WHERE condition(s). If you want to keep the "outer" join rows, check for those conditions in the ON clause. The difference between ON and WHERE is **when** the conditions are enforced - before or after the "outer" bit

Comment: @mathguy : Thanks.I couldn't have explained it better